# Embedded Media Field Title extraction with YouTube

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to create a dynamic video gallery using drupal's "Embedded Media Field"; works fine for now i'm able to add my youtube videos which displays correctly.

However, i'm looking for a way to change the title of the node (of type video, with one cck field of type : "Embedded Video") i tried 'node autotitle' but I don't see the video's 'title' in the available tokens.

To sum up; I want to be able to just put the link of youtube video and get the node title to be replaced by the youtube's actual title.

Any idea ? Or is there a better module for this ?

Comment: i am facing the same issue,,, did you find a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [very similar request on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1860814) in the [Video Embed Field](https://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module issue queue. They don't have an answer, but it'd be a good place to start. I use this module (instead of Embedded Media Field) and I've confirmed that it saves a chunk of metadata regarding the video in the Drupal database, so this technically should be possible.